# How to conver base64 to an image but not saving in the public folder in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, image, base64, laravel-8

I am working on a project in Laravel 8. I try to explain my problem as best I can.

1. The user can upload a photo
2. Next, the user has to crop the upgeloded photo.
3. Cropped photo is indicated in a base 64 code.
4. The problem I run into is: Before the photo is saved in public folder, the photo must be convorted into a photo with a photo name with it. There are a few things that need to be done before the photo is saved in public folder.

I have found several solutions on the internet but all solutions immediately save the photo in the public folder, but I don't want that. Before the photo is saved, a few things need to be done.
How can I fix that?

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly: You want to store images on your server, but dont want the images in public folder because you want to make sure only the right person can see the right image?

Comment: no!
before saving the image into the public folder, I want to give some effect to the image and can change the image name if needed.

Comment: Allright thanks for correcting me. So you want to know how to do the post processing? Is that wat you are asking?

Comment: yes :-)
But just decoding and giving a name and NOT saving in the public folder